# Cannot Log Into StackExchange

Tags: bug

I am having difficulty logging into stackexchange.  I keep on getting the error as shown below.  I can log into some of the other sites just fine like stackoverflow and meta.  However, I do not know all the urls for all of the other sites I am a member of.  I have tried logging in with Internet Explorer 8, Comodo Dragon 19.2, Firefox 10.0.1, and Opera 11.64.  All of them are giving me the same error.

[image]

Comment: Would help to know which login method you're attempting to use...

Comment: I was using: log in with Stack Exchange

Comment: I think it's worth noting that it says that Stack Exchange has already been notified of the problem, so you really don't need to post a question on Meta.

Comment: Ah, well according to balpha, [the sysadmins are having fun](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1017470#1017470). Don't know if the login is affected as well. I was complaining about the inbox.

Comment: I was having the same problem a few minutes ago.  Completely closing my browser (Firefox) and opening a new instance fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be working again, can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the Browser or Restart your machine. Make sure to clear all Browser  Caching before trying again. This way I got it worked for me few days back. Hope it will help you.